# How to count the stuck thread in the weblogic?

Tags: weblogic-10.x

There is a log showing the stuck thread marked by Weblogic:

```
<Apr 23, 2013 7:48:25 AM CST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '276' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "668" seconds working on the request "weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@23ba221b[
GET /XXX/saveInfo.do?fx=duration&info=25159,0,0,0,0,0,0,25153 HTTP/1.1
```

In my case, we observed if there are too many stuck threads, our server will be getting slower response time and eat more and more memory.

I want to make the count of stuck thread be a health index for my auto-reporting robot. How to count it other than log files ? Does any command or api help me to count stuck threads ?

---

summarized the solution (wlst sample code) from [@viccari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16170150/90909) :

```
from tempfile import mktemp

connect('your_account', 'your_account_pass', 'localhost:7001')

# dump thread details to a temp file
file = mktemp()
threadDump(writeToFile="true", serverName="your_server_name", fileName=file)

# count the string token "[STUCK]" by line
count = 0
f = open(file, "r")
for line in f.readlines():
  if line.find("STUCK") > 0:
    count = count + 1

print "NUM_OF_STUCK_THREADS: ", count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the thread pool health details using WLST (WebLogic Scripting Tools) scripts (if you are familiar with Python, it should not be a problem), or by accessing JMX counters using Java.

[This post](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=5582) contains a sample script that sends an alert email whenever stuck threads exist, and in the comments section you will find some samples of Java code acessing JMX counters. There are more examples of both methods on the web.